# Why does the second if-clause even execute?

Tags: fortran

I have a `do while` loop in my program, who's condition to continue keeps giving me off-by-one errors and I can't figure out why. It looks like this:

```
do while (ii .le. nri .and. ed(ii) .le. e1)
    ! do some stuff...
    ii = ii + 1
end do
```

where `ii` and `nri` are scalar integers, `e1` is a scalar real, and `ed` is a real array of length `nri`. What I expect to happen after the last run is that since `ii.le.nri` returns `.false.` the second condition is never tested, and I don't get any off-by-one problems. I've verified with the debugger that `ii.le.nri` really *does* return `.false.` - and yet the program crashes.

To verify my assumption that only one condition is tested, I even wrote a small test program, which I compiled with the same compiler options:

```
 program iftest
     implicit none

     if (returns_false() .and. returns_true()) then
         print *, "in if block"
     end if
 contains
     function returns_true()
         implicit none
         logical returns_true
         print *, "in returns true"
         returns_true = .true.
     end function

     function returns_false()
         implicit none
         logical returns_false
         print *, "in returns false"
         returns_false = .false
     end function
 end program
```

Running this program outputs, as I expected, only

```
 $ ./iftest
 in returns false
```

and exits. The second test is never run.

Why doesn't this apply to my `do while` clause?

Comment: When ii == nri then the second condition will be tested, and since you're testing floats in the second condition that could cause problems couldn't it?

Comment: @Kells1986: True - that's also something I have to fix. However, in this instance I've verified with the debugger that that is not the problem here; the program crashes with off-by-one error when `ii==nri`, not on the next run (which would be the problem with comparing reals).

Comment: @Kells1986: On the other hand (after a bit of thought on the matter): the reals will always have a relative difference on the order of about 10^-4, and I'm using 64-bit reals - that should never be subject to rounding error problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In contrast to some languages Fortran does not guarantee any particular order of evaluation of compound logical expressions.  In the case of your code, at the last go round the while loop the value of `ii` is set to `nri+1`. It is legitimate for your compiler to have generated code which tests `ed(nri+1)<=e1` and thereby refer to an element outside the bounds of `ed`.  This may well be the cause of your program's crash.

Your expectations are contrary to the Fortran standards prescriptions for the language.

If you haven't already done so, try recompiling your code with array-bounds checking switched on and see what happens.

As to why your test didn't smoke out this issue, well I suspect that all your test really shows is that your compiler generates a different order of execution for different species of condition and that you are not really comparing like-for-like.

Comment: Haha, yet another Fortran gotcha =) As you've noticed when answering so many of my questions the last couple of weeks, I'm quite new at this. Compiling with array-bounds checking was the reason I spotted this as an off-by-one, so that's what I'm doing already. `-O0` didn't change anything either, but if the order of the checks is undefined in the standard I suppose that's not strange. How should I put my brains logic into a set of instructions that the compiler will actually work with? =)

Comment: Fortran is a very easy programming language to use (certainly for those of us with 30 years experience), though it is perhaps a little difficult for those coming to it with minds already disturbed by exposure to other (and therefore lesser) languages. Fortran is a foreign country, we do thinks differently here.

Comment: try ed(min(ii,nri)) as a simple fix to see if that is indeed the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Extending the answer High Performance Mark, here is one way to rewrite the loop:

```
ii_loop: do

  if (ii .gt. nri) exit ii_loop
  if (ed(ii) .gt. e1) exit ii_loop

  ! do some stuff

  ii = ii + 1

end do ii_loop
```

Comment: Why not a simple ``do ii=iista,nri`` with a check for ``ed(ii)`` inside or something?

Comment: Yes, that would also work.  Probably simpler.  One could use the `if .. exit` for the `ed(ii)` test or have the code to be executed in an `IF` block.