# pgf90 cause segmentation fault when use optional logical argument

Tags: fortran, pgi

Just look at the following simple codes:

```
program hello

  call foo()

contains

  subroutine foo(bar)

    logical, intent(in), optional :: bar

    if (present(bar) .and. bar) then
      print *, 'hello'
    end if

  end subroutine foo

end program hello
```

When compiled it by `pgf90`, I got `Segmentation fault: 11` error, but it is ok when use `gfortran`. The problem should be at `present(bar) .and. bar`, but when `bar` is not given, `present(bar)` will be evaluated as `.false.`, and the following `bar` should not be evaluted, which is null in this case.

Comment: Or even my own modest contribution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16153272/why-does-the-second-if-clause-even-execute/16153786#16153786